# ELM map/fold understanding

Tags: functional-programming, elm, fold, map-function

I have a problem with understanding map or fold functions.

I have a task that takes an input `[1,1,2,2,3]` and need to convert it to the following output: `[[1,1],[2,2],[3]]`. So basically what I need to do is take the element from the array and check if it is possibly to group it with other elements that are the same. I need to use map or fold functions only.

Comment: You could do it using a fold, but it would be much easier with a simple recursive function.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why this function wasn't included (or something similar) in the main List library, but here is a quick and dirty version ([source](http://codegists.com/snippet/elm/groupbyelm_zemm_elm))

```
groupBy : List v -> (v -> k) -> List ( k, List v )
groupBy items f =
    case items of
        [] ->
            []

        x :: xs ->
            let
                key =
                    f x

                rest =
                    groupBy xs f
            in
                insertTo rest key x


insertTo : List ( k, List v ) -> k -> v -> List ( k, List v )
insertTo m key value =
    case m of
        [] ->
            [ ( key, [ value ] ) ]

        x :: xs ->
            if Tuple.first x == key then
                [ ( key, value :: Tuple.second x ) ] ++ xs
            else
                x :: insertTo xs key value
```

then you could call it like so

```
groupBy [1, 1, 2, 2, 3] identity
```

Comment: Maybe use [Dict](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/Dict) instead of a List of Tuples – Dict has logarithmic look-up, your insertTo is linear

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with:

```
module Main exposing (main)

import Html exposing (Html, text)


main : Html msg
main =
    [ 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 4 ] |> toGroups |> toString |> text


toGroups : List Int -> List (List Int)
toGroups xs =
    xs
        |> List.sort
        |> List.foldl makeGroups []


makeGroups : Int -> List (List Int) -> List (List Int)
makeGroups x groups =
    let
        this =
            if currentGroupValue == Just x then
                previousGroups ++ [ x::currentGroup ]
            else
                groups ++ [ [ x ] ]

        currentGroupValue =
            List.head currentGroup

        currentGroup =
            groups
                |> List.reverse
                |> List.head
                |> Maybe.withDefault []

        previousGroups =
            takeAllButLast groups

        takeAllButLast xs =
            List.take (List.length xs - 1) xs
    in
    this
```

So at a high level I do this:

1. sort the list;
2. make sub-lists out of the adjacent equal elements.

You can see it running and play with it here: https://ellie-app.com/7BQCWhW6na1/0.

Cheers!